# download .doc files on iphone via application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, import, ios4

in my app i have one option,
"Collect files" so if user press on this option, this request will send to server and server will reply....

my Que is
1: which type of file(extension) supported by iphone device, so user can download it and see data in it.

2.what is the maximum size of file we can use for download?

thank u in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the max file size. But for displaying .doc and .pdf (and a few more) will work fine. The easiest way yo display document is using a UIWebView. The UIWebView will allow you to display a wide array of filetypes, including .doc and .pdf.  For more information on supported types check out [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1630.html).

There is also the [QuickLook framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html) that has a few more bells and whistles for displaying documents your app don't support internally.